# Python - OpenCV module missing attribute CV_CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC

Tags: python, c++, opencv, computer-vision, stereo-3d

I am using OpenCV for stereo calibration of cameras. I have already performed calibration of individual cameras. And according to this [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#cv2.stereoCalibrate), Specifying pre-calculated camera matrices and distortion coefficients requires one to pass the flag `CV_CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC`

> If the intrinsic parameters can be estimated with high accuracy for each of the cameras individually (for example, using calibrateCamera() ), you are recommended to do so and then pass CV_CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC flag to the function along with the computed intrinsic parameters.

**But how to pass the flags?**
The values I have tried:

```
flags="CV_CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC"
flags=cv2.CV_CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC
flags=CV_CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC
```

I get the following errors (respectively):

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
Missing: module cv2 has no attribute CV_CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC
NameError: name 'CV_CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC' is not defined
```

Comment: I guess `cv2.CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC`

Comment: @Miki Thanks, that worked.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct name is:

```
cv2.CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC
```